# How to retrieve a photo from picasa as binary image

Tags: php, curl, picasa

Ok, so I am working with the plain Picasa API in PHP. (Not zend, just http calls). I am authenticated and can browse through albums and select photos.

The problem I am facing now is that I have a URL where a picture exists and I want to retrieve that picture's binary data with php. So far I have tried the samples below, but none of them downloaded any data.

```
$url = 'https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-T4v5svsA3JU/Tc7jEchmSYI/AAAAAAABAb8/MLXlXjKUyIg/s1024/Dies09_080509_5144.JPG';
$file = file_get_contents($url);
echo $file;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

So, how can I retrieve the binary data of a photo from Picasa?

Comment: what are you trying to do with it? save it to a file?

Comment: I'd like to rescale it. If I can do that with the data directly imagecreatefromstring it is preferred, but if I need to safe it in between that's fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of error did you get when using the first method? I've tested the code below and it works properly for me. This will output the image resized to a width of 250 px.

```
$url = 'https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-T4v5svsA3JU/Tc7jEchmSYI/AAAAAAABAb8/MLXlXjKUyIg/s1024/Dies09_080509_5144.JPG';
        $file = file_get_contents($url);
        $im = imagecreatefromstring($file);
        $im = imagescale($im, 250);

        header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
        imagejpeg($im);
```

Comment: I got no error, but no data either. The $file in your example was an empty string...

Comment: what is your OS and version of PHP? I tested that code and it works perfectly for me. Are you able to `file_get_contents` on any other URL? Does your php.ini show that `allow_url_fopen` is true?

Comment: Just ran this again and it does seem to work now... I had two more function in between (debug logging) that I removed to make the question more relevant, so apparently something went wrong in those function (outpunt sanitizing resulting in an empty string?). I just assumed Picasa blocked these kind of requests in some way. I'll go debug the other functions. Thanks for the help and the bounty is well earned. (I can award it in 23 hours... :-| )

Comment: Glad to help, I thought they might be blocking external requests too. I just used `curl` on the command line to test that.